# gdbserver - command not found

Tags: android, debugging, operating-system, gdbserver

I would like to perform debug operations on the Android open source platform.

I am trying to run "gdbserver :5039 --attach" in my terminal but I keep receiving "command not found".

I have built the Android OS using the "full_crespo-userdebug" configuration, which according to the android docs, should provide me with root access on my Nexus S phone?

How can I set things up so that I can debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug an android device you first need to run gdbserver on the device.

```
gdbserver :5039 --attach pid
```

then in your gingerbread source folder you need to run

```
source build/envsetup.sh
```

this will allow you to now run

```
gdbclient
```

which should connect to the gdbserver on device

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately the first line (gdbserver) results in 'Operation not permitted'

Comment: Note that my phone is also rooted, ie I see 'LOCK STATE - UNLOCKED' in the recovery screen.

Comment: adb root will fix that

Answer (score 2):

You can copy it from "$NDK_HOME/prebuild/$PLATFORM/gdbserver/gdbserver"
then use adb to push it to device and make it executable

Comment: or copy it to the /data/local/tmp folder so it can be executed:
`adb push {android-sdk}/ndk/{version}/prebuilt/android-arm64/gdbserver/gdbserver /data/local/tmp`